# no 'dimnames' attribute for array

Tags: r, csv, matrix

I'm trying to run the following R code:

```
X <- matrix(0, n_countries, n_languages)
for (index in 2:n_edges)
{
  i <- edgelist[index, 1]
  j <- edgelist[index, 2]
  perc <- edgelist[index, 3]
  if (perc > 0 ) 
    X[i,j] = 1

}
```

`edgelist` is a .csv file I've read in and the first few rows look like this:

```
                   V1  V2    V3
1   % bip posweighted  NA    NA
2                  31  18 1.000
3                 221  28 0.018
4                 185  12 0.000
5                  38  87 0.031
```

R says there's an error in the `if` statement,

```
Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, i, j, value = 1) : 
no 'dimnames' attribute for array
```

I've tried to apply the following solutions:

1. Removing the first row, with the NA values with

   `edgelist <- edgelist[-c(1),]`
2. And changing the column names to integers with

   `colnames(edgelist) <- c(1,2,3)`

None of these seem to work, as I keep getting the same error. I'm really unsure of how to solve this, as I don't understand why the for loop isn't just reading the rows into the matrix. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That is because your edgelist is of mode character instead of integer/numeric. In that case `edgelist[index, 1]` for example will give you `"31"` instead of `31`. You probably need to explicitly convert to numeric

Comment: I applied `edgelist_num <- as.numeric(unlist(edgelist))`, but unfortunately, the same error occurs.

Comment: did you get some warnings when converting to numeric? Check the answer below

Comment: Yes, Michael's answer worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to convert the first column from character to numeric after removing the first row.

```
edgelist[,1] <- as.numeric(edgelist[,1])
```

Once you've removed the first row, be sure to change your `for()` loop to run from `1:n_edges` instead of `2:n_edges`

Another faster solution would come from the `Matrix` package by using the `sparseMatrix()` function to create a matrix like this. For this function, you give it your row index, column index and value that you want to put in there and it'll create the matrix for you. Although to use it, you might have to convert it from a `dgCMatrix` to a regular `matrix`:

```
install.packages("Matrix")
library(Matrix)
Y <-   sparseMatrix(
         i = edgelist[,1],
         j = edgelist[,2],
         x = 1*(edgelist[,3] > 0)
       )
Y <- as.matrix(Y)
```